# Bounds of the derivative of a bounded band-limited function

Tags: bandwidth, derivative

Let $f(t)$ be a function with properties:

$$\begin{array}{ll}
t\in\mathbf{R}&t\text{ is in reals}\\
f(t)\in\mathbf{R}\text{ for all } t&f(t)\text{ is in reals}\\
|f(t)|<A\text{ for all }t&\text{absolute value of }f(t)\text{ is bounded above by }A\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \ e^{- i \omega t} \ {\rm d}t = 0\text{ for all }|\omega|\ge B&f(t)\text{ is band-limited by frequency B in radians}
\end{array}$$

Given $A$ and $B,$ what is the tight upper bound for $|f'(t)|,$ the absolute value of the derivative of the function?

Nothing else shall be assumed about $f(t)$ than what has been stated above. The bound should accommodate for this uncertainty.

For a sinusoid of amplitude $A$ and frequency $B,$ the maximum absolute value of the derivative is $AB.$ I wonder if this is an upper bound, and in that case also the tight upper bound. Or maybe a non-sinusoidal function has a steeper slope.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211817/derivative-of-band-limited-functions)?

Comment: @Tendero thanks. There, the signal energy is known, rather than the peak absolute value as in my question.

Comment: See [my answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/49680/235) for the bound you seek.  It says More generally, a result due to Bernstein says that if the _maximum frequency_ in a generic $x(t)$ bounded within $[-1,1]$ is $f_0$, that is, $X(f) = 0$ for $|f| > f_0$, then 
$$\max \left| \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right| \leq 2\pi f_0.$$

Comment: Based on the sharp version of Bernstein's inequality, from Dilip's linked answers, MBaz's edited answer and the literature cited, $AB$ is indeed the sharp (I called it tight meaning the same) upper bound for the maximum absolute value of the derivative, a full-scale sinusoid at exactly the band limit (not strictly allowed by the constraints I give) making the inequality an equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll be interested in Bernstein's inequality, which I first learned about in [Lapidoth, A Foundation in Digital Communication](https://www.afidc.ethz.ch/A_Foundation_in_Digital_Communication/Home.html) (page 92).

With a well-behaved signal $f(t)$ as you defined it above (in particular, $f(t)$ is integrable and bandlimited to $B\,\text{Hz}$, and $\text{sup}\,|f(t)| = A$), then $$\left|\frac{\text{d}f(t)}{\text{d}t}\right| \leq 2AB\pi.
$$

Note that the original result by Bernstein established a bound of $4AB\pi$; later, that bound was tightened to $2AB\pi$.

---

I have spent some time reading Zygmund's "Trigonometric Series"; all I'll say is that it is the perfect remedy for those under the impression that they know trigonometry. A full understanding of the proof is beyond my mathematical skill, but I think I can highlight the main points.

First, what Zygmund calls *Bernstein's inequality* is a more limited result. Given the trigonometric polynomial $$T(x) = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty c_k e^{jkx}$$ (with real $x$), then $$\max_x |T'(x)| \leq n \max_x |T(x)|$$ with strict inequality unless $T$ is a monomial $A \cos(nx+\alpha)$.

To generalize this we need a preliminay result. Consider a function $F$ that is in $\text{E}^\pi$ and in $\text{L}^2$. ($\text{E}^\sigma$ is the class of integral functions of type at most $\sigma$ -- this is one of the places where my math starts to fray at the edges. My understanding is that this is a mathematically rigorous way of stating that $f=\text{IFT}\lbrace F \rbrace$ has bandwidth $\sigma$.)

For any such $F$ we have the interpolation formula $$F(z) = \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}F_1(z),$$ where $z$ is complex and $$F_1(z) = F'(0) + \frac{F(0)}{\pi} + \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty {^\prime} (-1)^nF(n) \left( \frac{1}{z-n}+\frac{1}{n} \right).$$ (This is theorem 7.19.)

Now we can state the main theorem. If:

- $F$ is in $\text{E}^\sigma$ with $\sigma>0$
- $F$ is bounded on the real axis
- $M=\sup |F(x)|$ for real $x$

then $$|F'(x)| \leq \sigma M$$ with equality possible iff $F(z) = a e^{j\sigma z} + b e{-j\sigma x}$ for arbitrary $a,b$. We suppose that $\sigma=\pi$ (otherwise we take $F(z\pi/\sigma)$ instead of $F(z)$.)

To prove this, we write the derivative of $F$ using the interpolation formula above: $$F'(x) = F_1(x)\cos(\pi x)+\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nF(n)}{(x-n)^2}.$$ Setting $x=1/2$ we get $$F'(1/2) = \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nF(n)}{(2n-1)^2}$$ which implies $$|F'(1/2)| \leq \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} = \frac{4M\pi^2}{4\pi} = M\pi.$$

Now we need a nice little trick: Take an arbitrary $x_0$ and define $G(z) = F(x_0+z-1/2)$. Then, $$|F'(x_0)| = |G'(1/2)| \leq M\pi.$$

(TODO: Show the proof for the case of equality. Define $\sum \prime$.)

Comment: I recalled seeing something like this here, but could not find it by searching without the Bernstein keyword. Your $B$ is in Hz, so the right side of the inequality would be $2AB$ in my notation.

Comment: Now I find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109045/functions-whose-fourier-transform-vanishes-outside-of-a-small-interval) but compared to its answer the bound in your answer is off by a factor of 2.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo As pointed out in MattL's answer, the sinusoid $\sin(2\pi Bt)$ has maximum derivative $2\pi B$.  This  meets Bernstein's bound, as stated in my answer here on dsp.SE (cited in a comment on your question) and in my answer on math.SE that you found, with equality.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo I found the proof given by Pinksy [here](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=PyISCgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&ots=Zg18DKLqQo&sig=e9tUndTfMpDKgS9FjNH4n8HPidU#v=onepage&q=bernstein&f=false) (I hope that link works!). He definitely uses $4AB\pi$ as the bound, not $2AB\pi$.

Comment: (The proof is in page 122 in the link I provided above)

Comment: @MBaz Your link works indeed! At the end of the section 2.3.8 they say that the best known version of Bernstein's inequality has the factor 2 instead of 4, which is sharp, and that for details consult Zygmund (1959) Vol. 2, p. 276. I think that's Zygmund, A. Trigonometric series. 2nd ed. Vol. II. Cambridge University Press, New York 1959.

Comment: RP Boas, [Some theorems on Fourier transforms and conjugate trigonometric integrals](https://www.ams.org/tran/1936-040-02/S0002-9947-1936-1501874-9/S0002-9947-1936-1501874-9.pdf), Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 40 (2), 287-308, 1936 cites the relevant articles by Bernstein, Szegö, and Zygmund,  already with the sharp bound, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Excellent! I had missed that note at the end of section 2.3.8. I'll update my answer. Also: that book by Zygmund is in my university's library, but it's not online. I'll take it out tomorrow and see what it says.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo I have the book, but I'm still trying to make sense of the proof; I'll post it once I'm confident I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

In general you would get something like this, but it might not be tight:

$$\begin{align}|f'(t)|&=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}j\omega F(j\omega)e^{-j\omega t}d\omega\right|\\&\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\omega||F(j\omega)|d\omega\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c}|\omega||F(j\omega)|d\omega\\&\le \frac{|\omega_c|}{2\pi}\int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c}|F(j\omega)|d\omega\\&=\frac{\omega_c}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\omega_c}|F(j\omega)|d\omega\tag{1}\end{align}$$

The upper bound on $|f(t)|$ is of course implicit in $|F(j\omega)|$.

For a sinusoid $A\sin(\omega_ct)$, $(1)$ gives $A\omega_c$ as an upper bound, as expected.

Comment: @Olli Niemitalo , I had derived the sinusoid case I think this is the general case we were looking at. Thanks Matt L.

Comment: Hi Matt, I really like your answer but I have a question, How you make sure that $\int\limits_0^{\omega_c} |F(j\omega)|d\omega < \infty$ is always absolute integrable?

Comment: @Joako: In general you don't know if that integral converges. If it doesn't, the bound is of course useless. I would think that in most practical cases the integral does converge.